# Split complex equation

Tags: complex

Sometimes it is useful to split a complex equation into its real and imaginary parts. Consider the following ode

```
ode = y'''[x] - k^3*y[x] == I*k*a*((2*x - c)*(y''[x] - k^2*y[x]) + 2*y[x])
bc1 = y'[0] == 0;
bc2 = y''[1] + k^2*y[1]/(1 - c) == 0;
```

in which `y[x]` is a complex function with a real independent variable `x`, $a$ is a real parameter, and $k$ and $c$ are complex parameters. If we write `y[x]=yr[x]+I yi[x]`, `k=kr+ I ki`, and `c=cr+I ci`, how can I transfer the system in terms of two real equations `odereal` and `odeimag` togeter with their boundary conditions `bc1real`, `bc1imag`, `bc2real`, `bc2imag`.

For example,

```
y[x_] := yr[x] + I*yi[x]
bc1 /. y -> y[x]
(*I Derivative[1][yi][0] + Derivative[1][yr][0] == 0*)
```

**Problem: We can see that the real and imaginary parts still are written together in the boundary condition. Note also that I did not need to solve the equation at present.** What I want is, for example,

```
bc1real = Derivative[1][yr][0] == 0
bc1imag = Derivative[1][yi][0] == 0
```

with a similar split-form for the `ode` and `bc2`.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

## Splitting complex equations (or expressions) into real and imaginary parts

#### Uses: I, Re, Im, Assumptions, Alternatives (|), Element, Simplify, Map

I find this comes up most most often with equations. So will illustrate it that way. I just made up the equation below. Key idea is that a and c are assumed real. It's usually the case that I occurs explicitly.

```
exampleComplexEquation = Expand[(a + I)^4 + 2 a^2 == 30 + 40*c*I];


exampleComplexEquation2 = a + b*I == 3 + 4 I;
```

Two functions are defined as below. Look up Element to understand acceptable values for `arg`. These functions are meant to illustrate an approach.

```
realPart[ex_, arg_] := 
 Simplify[Map[Re, ex], Assumptions -> Element[arg, Reals]]

imagPart[ex_, arg_] := 
 Simplify[Map[Im, ex], Assumptions -> Element[arg, Reals]]
```

And an example of use. The functions are meant as examples rather than complete solutions.

```
realEquation = realPart[exampleComplexEquation, a | c]
```

> ```
>   a^4 == 29 + 4 a^2
> ```

```
imagEquation = imagPart[exampleEquation, a | c]
```

> ```
>   a^3 == a + 10 c
> ```

You can also use Solve directly in some cases. The syntax for Element here is a bit different.

```
Solve[exampleComplexEquation2 && Element[{a, b}, Reals], {a, b}]
```

> ```
>   {{a -> 3, b -> 4}}
> ```

```
exampleComplexEquation3 = (a + 2*b*I)^2 == 3 + 4*I;

Solve[exampleComplexEquation3 && Element[{a, b}, Reals], {a, b}]
```

> ```
>    {{a -> -2, b -> -(1/2)}, {a -> 2, b -> 1/2}}
> ```

Hope this helps lead you down a productive road.

Comment: your approach is informative but it is cannot deal with a simple ode with an exponential. e.g. extending func definition: `realPart[eq_, real_, imag_] := 
 Simplify[Map[Re, eq], Assumptions -> Element[real, Reals] && Element[imag,Complexes]]; imagPart[eq_, real_, imag_] := 
 Simplify[Map[Im, eq], Assumptions -> Element[real, Reals] && Element[imag, Complexes]];` testing with `ode = Expand[I*(y''[x] + k^2) + a == 0]`, `realode = realPart[ode, x | a, y | k]` gives `a == Im[k^2] + Im[(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]]`. Well, it is expected to yield `a == 2 Re[k] Im[k] + Im[(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]]`.